# Stopping main thread execution

Tags: ios, multithreading

My question is simple:

I want to stop the main thread current execution after a set timer, can it be done?

for example:

MainThread running:

```
while(true) {
    i++;
}
```

I want to stop after 10 secs so it will continue to the next command.

Notice, The main thread is actually constantly doing CPU work, its not sleeping...

---

More specific, My problem is:

My main thread is running JavaScript that might be buggy and run forever, calling this method must be done in the main thread.

I want to stop the main thread from executing this JavaScript after 10 secs (and move to the next command, or a catch block), I presume if it hasn't finished after 10 secs it means the javascript code is buggy and I don't want to continue running.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:<some java script that may take forever>];
```

This is a problem, I can't interrupt the main thread, I can send a message to the message queue as the main thread is busy with CPU work.

Can this be done?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What you are doing there will make your customers hate your guts.

Comment: Yes, just to echo @gnasher729. What is the actual thing you are trying to do? What is it that you want your app to do. Not what you think you need to do in code.

Comment: Never block the main thread

Comment: I am running a javascript to do some rendering of html webview,
But this is an external javascript, that I do not have control over, I want to protect the app from crushing if its buggy, I don't think the users will hate me for that :)
And again, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString must be done in the UIThread, it sends a message to its message queue